# Typescript Redux - Type Checking with Parameter Props from Dispatch Props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

Have read a couple of articles on this but they don't seem to work for me. I have two interfaces declared. One is intended to represent the component props which are passed by the parent:

```
interface MyProps {
    name: string;
}
```

And then another interface which represents the props created by the redux connect() function:

```
interface DispatchProps {
    addData: (someData: any) => void;
}
```

So to get decent type checking my understanding is I need to create my react component using generics:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyProps, {}> {
    render() {
        return (
            <span onClick={this.props.addData}>{this.props.name}</span>
        );
    }
    ...
}
```

The problem is that typescript is now upset because this.props.addData does not exist. So I do what the internets tells me like a good little boy and add an intersection type:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyProps & DispatchProps, {}> {}
```

But The problem is simply shifted because in the parent component typescript is now upset because in my render I have:

```
render() {
    return (
        <MyComponent name="a name" />
    );
}
```

Because "Property addData is missing on type {}".

So what am I missing here? How can I combine what redux does with what react does in a way that allows me to get type checking in my components?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out the problem wasn't with my interfaces/generics, the problem was with my import statement in the parent. I am posting the answer in the hopes it might help someone else in the future.

I had:

```
import {MyComponent} from './MyComponent';
```

But this was importing the COMPONENT CLASS instead of the CONNECTED COMPONENT generated in this line:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);
```

importing the default instead and adding the correct generics to the connect function solved my problem.